# What is the difference between cat source.txt | grep x and grep x source.txt?

Tags: linux

I saw an example where some one did this:

```
cat source.txt | grep a
```

But I always do it like:

```
grep a source.txt
```

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Not a great deal.  `grep` (like many standard *nix utils) can process either stdin or files named as command-line args.

Comment: One of them [annoys old-fashioned Unix users](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)... ("Useless use of cat" or UUOC)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What is the pipe symbol used for in general?

Comment: For [piping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_pipe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a classical “useless use of cat” (*UUOC*).